# How to extract parts of an xts in R

Tags: r, lookup

I have some data in R,

```
             Open    High     Low   Close
2017-09-01 1.29360 1.29951 1.29052 1.29495
2017-09-03 1.29600 1.29660 1.29444 1.29535
2017-09-04 1.29536 1.29643 1.29124 1.29300
2017-09-05 1.29306 1.30440 1.29088 1.30331
2017-09-06 1.30331 1.30820 1.30181 1.30471
2017-09-07 1.30472 1.31381 1.30325 1.31319
2017-09-08 1.31319 1.32239 1.31233 1.31945
2017-09-10 1.31816 1.31978 1.31736 1.31769
2017-09-11 1.31769 1.32223 1.31593 1.31764
2017-09-12 1.31766 1.33145 1.31703 1.33097
2017-09-13 1.33096 1.33286 1.31836 1.32040
2017-09-14 1.32039 1.34055 1.31501 1.33955
2017-09-15 1.33955 1.36159 1.33922 1.35871
2017-09-17 1.35579 1.36029 1.35579 1.35921
2017-09-18 1.35921 1.36181 1.34646 1.35176
2017-09-19 1.35176 1.35515 1.34683 1.35178
2017-09-20 1.35178 1.36573 1.34517 1.34914
2017-09-21 1.34914 1.35861 1.34706 1.35761
2017-09-22 1.35760 1.35955 1.34496 1.34935
2017-09-24 1.34872 1.35339 1.34832 1.35261
2017-09-25 1.35262 1.35706 1.34308 1.34816
2017-09-26 1.34816 1.35139 1.34094 1.34385
2017-09-27 1.34386 1.34389 1.33634 1.33753
2017-09-28 1.33754 1.34551 1.33427 1.34159
2017-09-29 1.34160 1.34258 1.33497 1.33963
```

If I choose a date of 2017-09-01 I want it to return the value of the Open column, so 1.29360.

This is the format.

```
structure(c(1.2936, 1.296, 1.29536, 1.29306, 1.30331, 1.30472, 
1.29951, 1.2966, 1.29643, 1.3044, 1.3082, 1.31381, 1.29052, 1.29444, 
1.29124, 1.29088, 1.30181, 1.30325, 1.29495, 1.29535, 1.293, 
1.30331, 1.30471, 1.31319), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1504224000, 
1504396800, 1504483200, 1504569600, 1504656000, 1504742400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
"High", "Low", "Close")))
```

TIA

Comment: This is better than your last question because it focuses on a single issue, but **please show what you tried**. Your questions will get a fast and helpful response if (1) you show what you tried, and (2) you share data [reproducibly. This link has a good tutorial on how to share data reproducibly.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: In this case, `dput(head(your_data))` or `dput(droplevels(head(your_data)))` will make a subset of your data copy/pasteable, and it  will show the structure of your data (data frame? Matrix? something else?) and it will provide the column classes (is your date column a `Date` class, or maybe `POSIXct`, or `character`, something else?), all of which is important to know how to help you.

Comment: All right, that's #2 taken care of (it would be best if you edit it into your question), how about #1?

Comment: Like I've said, I don't know ANY functions in R, so haven't found anything to be useful yet.

Comment: And like I've said, *asking questions here does not make a good replacement for reading tutorials that cover the basics of R.* [The R tag wiki has a great list of resources for starting with R](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). I've heard a lot of good things about Swirl recently.

Comment: Is this `data['2017-09-01']$Open` what you want?